# Peoplepicker's searching in all forest

Tags: people-picker

I have a forest `company.com` with several domains in it. How to make people-picker to search users only in a specific domain?

I used

```
stsadm -o setproperty -url url -pn peoplepicker-distributionlistsearchdomains -pv dev.company.com
```

"get property" returns value `dev.company.com`, all seems to be ok. But I'm still getting people from other domains in results when trying to add users to a site.

Maybe because of trusts? If so, how to set people-picker on users only in dev.company.com?